# ui is different in different devices in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout

I have designed a ui using flutter first I checked it in my phone which is Moto g5s plus the ui looks goods and I occupies entire screen but when I open the same app in iPhone 11 pro max I am getting a huge empty space but when I open it in iPhone 8 then the ui looks fine as it is in Moto g5s plus. I want to know how to have same consistent ui across different device sizes in flutter?

```
class Login extends StatefulWidget
{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return LoginState();
  }

}
class LoginState extends State<Login>
{
  String _email,_password;
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();


  @override
  void initState()
  {
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget _progressBar(AuthProvider authProvider)
  {
    //print("progress"+authProvider.progressStatus.toString());

        return Visibility(
          maintainSize: true,
          maintainAnimation: true,
          maintainState: true,
          visible: authProvider.progressStatus,
          child: Container(
              child: Center(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 60,
                    height: 60,
                    child: Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                offset: Offset(0.0, 1.0), //(x,y)
                                blurRadius: 1.0,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
              )
          ),
        );
      }
  Widget _emailTextField(AuthProvider authProvider)
  {
    return TextFormField(
          onChanged: (String value){
              authProvider.checkEmail(value);
          },
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: "Email id",
              errorText: authProvider.emailStatus ? null : "Enter a valid email",
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(32.0),
              )
          ),
          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
          validator: (String value){
            if(value.isEmpty || !RegExp(r"[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?").hasMatch(value))
            {
              return "Enter a valid email";
            } else {
              return null;
            }
          },
          onSaved: (String value){
            _email = value;
          },
        );
  }
  Widget _passwordTextField(AuthProvider authProvider)
  {
    //print("pass check "+authProvider.passStatus.toString());
    return TextFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Password",
              filled: true,
              errorText: authProvider.passStatus ? null : "Password is too short",
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(32.0),
              ),
              fillColor: Colors.white
          ),
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          obscureText: true,
          onChanged: (String value){
            authProvider.checkPassword(value);
          },
          validator: (String value){
            if(value.isEmpty)
            {
              return "Enter a valid password";
            }
            else if(value.length < 8)
            {
              return "Password is too short";
            }
            else
            {
              return null;
            }
          },
          onSaved: (String value){
            _password = value;
          },
        );
  }
  void _login(AuthProvider authProvider)
  {

    if(!_formKey.currentState.validate())
      {
        return;
      }
    _formKey.currentState.save();

    Map<String,String> map = new Map();
    map['email'] = _email;
    map['password'] = _password;
    authProvider.login(map);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final authProvider = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context);
    if(authProvider.loginStatus != null && authProvider.loginStatus != "success")
    {
      _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text('${authProvider.loginStatus}',
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFe5e5e5),
      ));
    }
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 48, 0, 0),
                      child: Text(
                        "Take Orders",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: Text(
                        "Track the Best Selling Items",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,fontSize: 16),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 0, 16, 0),
                      child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/undraw_booking.svg',width: 100.0,height: 280.0,),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 0, 0, 0),
                      child:Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                              "Login To ",
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontSize: 20)
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "Take orders",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,fontSize: 20),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 8, 16, 0),
                      child: Form(
                        key: _formKey,
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            //_emailTextField(_loginBloc),
                            Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 8, 0, 0),
                              child:  _emailTextField(authProvider),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 8, 0, 0),
                              child:  _passwordTextField(authProvider),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 8, 0, 0),
                              child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                child: RaisedButton(
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)
                                  ),
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(64, 12, 64, 12),
                                  color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                                  textColor: Colors.white,
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Login",
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: (){
                                    _login(authProvider);
                                  },
                                ) ,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),

                    ),


                  ],
                ),
              )
          ),
          _progressBar(authProvider),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

[images of emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZACH.jpg)

Comment: It is more likely that you didn't program that correctly but without a code nobody will help you with it

Comment: use Cupertino Widgets for ios and Material for android

Comment: Stack right in the Scaffold body... that is your problem... Why did you even use it???? If you don't know how to use stack then it will make more harm then good...

Comment: i used it because i want to have circular progress indicator in the middle of the screen.

Comment: what should i do to get the circular indicator in the  middle of the  screen and how to handle ui in different screen sizes?

Comment: You don't want to do it with Stack... or definitely not the way you did it... Get rid of the stack in Scaffold body and add it where you need it.. I'm not gonna rework your code.. that is not what StackOverflow is for.. Go to the documentation and learn more about each widget before you do something.. Or create a simplified version of the issue where we can reproduce it instead of entire code from your 'app'

Answer (score 1):

without seeing code i cannot advise you proper solution however, i guess that tricks will solve your many issues.

instead of using fixed values

try to use

```
 height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
 width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
```

you can also use them like

```
 height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.80, // 80% of screen height 
 width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.35, // 35% of screen width
```

Hope will help you

Comment: I have updated the question with the code and screenshot please check it